# Updating Values not working in Mysql Table

Tags: mysql, updates

I m having a table column named MAXT which contains negative and positive floating point values. That column type is `float`. 
My problem is while i m using this column in update query it has no effect. 
For Example,

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET MAXTCLASS='A9' WHERE MAXT = 2.5; is running successfully. But

UPDATE TABLE1 SET MAXTCLASS='A9' WHERE MAXT = -2.5;
```

is nor updated the values neither showing any error. Pls Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show us table structure and some data to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Sangeetha Krishnan Which version of mysql you are using?

Answer (score 0):

For test i have created the sample table and tested works fine.It's getting updated in Mysql Server version: 5.1.60

```
desc X11;

| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| d1    | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

update X11 set id = 4 where d1 =-2.5;

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

 mysql> select * from X11;

+------+------+
| d1   | id   |
+------+------+
|  2.5 |    1 |
| -2.5 |    4 |
+------+------+

 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also working with version I am using (for both 2.5 and -2.5)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your reply.I dont why others DB Supports the query. But now The problem has been solved by changing field type float into decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Check the table structure if the data field you are trying to change is not marked with the 'unsigned'.

If so, change the data type, removing this option in the structure.